# Perl threads - calling subroutine from module (pm)

Tags: multithreading, perl

what is the correct syntax to start a thread of a subroutine that is defined in an extra perl module?

perl program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use forks;
require testModule;

# before solution - thanks ysth!
# testModule->main will not work!
#my $thr1 = threads->new(\&testModule->main, "inputA_1", "inputB_1");
#my $thr2 = threads->new(\&testModule->main, "inputA_2", "inputB_2");

# solved
#my $thr1 = threads->new(\&testModule::main, "inputA_1", "inputB_1");
#my $thr2 = threads->new(\&testModule::main, "inputA_2", "inputB_2");
my @output1 = $thr1->join;
my @output2 = $thr2->join;
```

perl module testModule.pm:

```
package testModule;
sub main{
    my @input = @_;
    #some code
    return ($output1, $output2)
}
```

What is the exact system call for *testModule->main*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added the solution into the perl code - thanks ysth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right:

```
...threads->new( \&testModule::main, "inputA_1", "inputB_1" );
```

`->` is only for class/instance method calls; if you wanted it to be called as a class method (which would make `@input` get the class name as well as "inputA_1" and "inputB_1"), then you would do:

```
...threads->new( sub { testModule->main(@_) }, "inputA_1", "inputB_1" );
```

Comment: Thanks, this was to simple ;)